# In Java, Is there a more optimised way to merge multiple JSONArrays other than iterating and inserting individual elements?

Tags: java

I currently have multiple separate JSONArrays which I would like to merge into a single JSONArray. I tried finding some answers and all i could find was to iterate the array and appending individual elements to a new array.

I'd like to know if there is a more optimised way to do this as I might have a large number of JSONArrays.

I tried finding some answers and all i could find was to iterate the array and appending individual elements to a new array.

Consider the code example below.

```
JSONArray arr1 = [
    {
        "id" : 123,
        "name" : aaa
    },
    {
        "id" : 456,
        "name" : bbb
    }
];

JSONArray arr2 = [
    {
        "id" : 12,
        "name" : ccc
    },
    {
        "id" : 555,
        "name" : ddd
    },
    {
        "id" : 7986,
        "name" : eee
    }
];
```

Is there a way to merge these and obtain a single JSONArray as mentioned below.

```
JSONArray merged = [
    {
        "id" : 123,
        "name" : aaa
    },
    {
        "id" : 456,
        "name" : bbb
    },
    {
        "id" : 12,
        "name" : ccc
    },
    {
        "id" : 555,
        "name" : ddd
    },
    {
        "id" : 7986,
        "name" : eee
    }
];
```

Comment: First question: Which `JSONArray` class are you using? I think there are at least two.

Comment: You could use `Arrays.stream()`, `Stream.flatMap()` and `Stream.toArray()`. Not optimised for memory/CPU but optimised for human readability.

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder writes, there is an android org.json.JSONArray, and a net.sf.json.JSONArray, and possibly others (not to mention those that spell it as JsonArray ...). Also, there is bound to be differences between versions of each particular library. The answer depends on which library you are using.

Comment: Sorry that i forgot to mention that. I'm using org.json.JSONArray.